# Dynamic variables in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i have a dynamic form in react js which gives me a output like the following -

```
screes are here of console logs - http://imgur.com/a/w9KYN
```

> Object
>   keys
>   :
>   Array[2]
>   0
>   :
>   1
>   1
>   :
>   2
>   length
>   :
>   2
>   **proto**
>   :
>   Array[0]
>   names-1
>   :
>   "bill"
>   names-2
>   :
>   "wil"
>   noItems-1
>   :
>   50
>   noItems-2
>   :
>   50050
>   tVal-1
>   :
>   500
>   tVal-2
>   :
>   2520
>   values-1
>   :
>   500
>   values-2
>   :
>   500

Console.log(JSON.Stringfy(values)) -

```
{"keys":[1,2],"names-1":"will","values-1":200,"noItems-1":2002,"tVal-1":200,"names-2":"bill","values-2":200,"noItems-2":2002,"tVal-2":200}
```

if i delete one or two form items from the middle - here is the output -

```
{"keys":[1,4],"names-1":"will","values-1":200,"noItems-1":2002,"tVal-1":200,"names-4":"dill","values-4":300,"noItems-4":300,"tVal-4":300}
```

I can read the keys array in such manner -

```
console.log('Recived values:', values.keys);
```

But i want to iterate the values, Can someone help me in iterating the values? to be specific how go i get 'names-1' and 'names-2'? as the string is based on the keys array?

The code snippet is here :

```
hadleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.form.validateFields((err, values) => {
        if(!err){
            var lis = values.keys;
            this.setState({
                controlKey: lis
            });
            lis.forEach(function(value){
                /* need help to iterate here*/
            })
            console.log('Recived values:', values.keys);
        }
    })
}
```

my render component looks something like this -

```
const {getFieldDecorator, getFieldValue}  = this.props.form;
    const formItemLayoutWithOutLabel = {
        wrapperCol: {
            xs: { span: 24, offset: 0 },
            sm: { span: 20, offset: 4 },
            },
    };
    getFieldDecorator('keys', {initialValue:[]});
    const keys = getFieldValue('keys');
    const formItems = keys.map((k, index) => {
        return(
            <div>
                <Row>
                    <Col span={6}>
                        <FormItem
                            label={index === 0 ? 'Item' : ''}
                            required={false}
                            key={k}
                        >
                            {getFieldDecorator(`names-${k}`, {
                                validateTrigger: ['onChange'],
                                rules: [{
                                    required: true,
                                    whitespace: true,
                                    message: 'Please input item name',
                                }],
                            })(
                                <Input placeholder="Item Name" style={{width: '75%'}}/>
                            )}
                        </FormItem>
                    </Col>
                    <Col span={6}>
                        <FormItem
                            label={index === 0 ? 'Value/Unit' : ''}
                            required={false}
                            key={k}
                        >
                            {getFieldDecorator(`values-${k}`, {
                                validateTrigger: ['onChange'],
                                rules: [{
                                    required: true,
                                    message: 'Please input item value',
                                }],
                            })(
                                <InputNumber placeholder="Item value per unit" style={{width: '75%'}}/>
                            )}
                        </FormItem>
                    </Col>
                    <Col span = {6}>
                        <FormItem
                            label={index === 0 ? 'Total Unit' : ''}
                            required={false}
                            key={k}
                        >
                            {getFieldDecorator(`noItems-${k}`, {
                                validateTrigger: ['onChange'],
                                rules: [{
                                    required: true,
                                    message: 'Please input total number of items',
                                }],
                            })(
                                <InputNumber placeholder="Please input total number of items" style={{width: '75%'}}/>
                            )}
                        </FormItem>
                    </Col>
                    <Col span={6}>
                        <FormItem
                            label={index === 0 ? 'Total Value' : ''}
                            required={false}
                            key={k}
                        >
                            {getFieldDecorator(`tVal-${k}`, {
                                validateTrigger: ['onChange'],
                                rules: [{
                                    required: true,
                                    message: 'Total Value',
                                }],
                            })(
                                <InputNumber placeholder="Total Value" style={{width: '75%'}}/>
                            )}
                            <Icon
                                className="dynamic-delete-button"
                                type="minus-circle-o"
                                disabled={keys.length === 1}
                                onClick={() => this.remove(k)}
                            />
                        </FormItem>
                    </Col>
                </Row>
            </div>
```

Comment: so what is values? So does `lis` contain an array of arrays or is it an object?

Comment: see the backquotes portion, it has got the console.log(values)

Comment: it's an array of objects isn't it? It's kind of hard to tell with the way you're showing your array. I'd prefer what you'd see in the console.log, where there's vertical spacing.

Comment: screens of console log are her http://imgur.com/a/w9KYN

Comment: Post your array structure properly. console.log JSON.stringify. It's hard to answer without this.

Comment: added screens link but i m not allowed to post images here so the link is - http://imgur.com/a/w9KYN

Comment: Rashi what they are asking is that you copy the output from `console.log(JSON.stringify(values))` and paste that in your question so we can see it as a json object in its string representation. its very hard for us to give an answer when we have no idea what the data is like. Dont post images, those links will expire and this question will be obsolete for others later. just post text :)

Comment: opps sorry, i got the JSON object and edited the question, please have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you want to do is define the variables to be used

```
const myVars = ['names', 'noItems', 'tVal', 'values']
let totalVal = 0;
lis.forEach( (value) => {
    myVars.forEach( myVar => {
        const key = `${myVar}-${value}`
        console.log(`${key}: ${values[key]}`)
        if (myVar === 'tVal') { 
            totalVal += values[key]
        }
    })
})
console.log(totalVal);
```

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/xng5taff/)

so basically what i'm doing here is using the `myVars` array to define which keys i'm interested in. From there I am looping over the keys array to know which variable to create aka `name-number`. then values (the original object) bracket or sub notation on that key to get the actual value.

Comment: this did the job! thanx

Comment: @RashiSonowal glad I could help! :)

Comment: suppose tVal is an int then how will i add those values? i mean i want to add all the 'tVals-{number}'

Comment: @RashiSonowal not sure I follow what you mean. are you saying you have a key like `names-1` and `20-1` ?

Comment: i mean like 'tVal-1:200' and there is a 'tVal-3:300' how do i add those two up for in the loop?

Comment: @RashiSonowal ah gotcha. Well if you only need to add this one you can simply just do a check. if you need to do more complex groupings and math operations I would categorize the data. I would use an object with an array of values for each type of data.

Comment: @RashiSonowal edited my answer to show how you can add a simple check. Let me know if you have more questions :)